# PHP SoapClient fails after one request

Tags: php, soap

I have a PHP script that uses SoapClient to access an API.  After connecting, if I just make one request, it works as expected but when I try to make a second request with the same SoapClient object, i get a `Bad Request` error.

I believe the issue may have to do with my server configuration because the same PHP code works fine in another computer with an older version of PHP but on my test and production servers which have been updated to PHP 5.6 both experience this error.

Code:

```
    <?php

class ReportAPI
{
  protected $reportDataObject = null;

  public function __construct($url = 'URL', $username = 'username', $password = 'pass') {
    $this->client = new SoapClient($url , array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'keep_alive' => true));
  }
  public function getReportData($reportID) {
    return $this->getDataObject($reportID)->data;
  }
  public function getReportCount($reportID) {
    return $this->getDataObject($reportID)->result_count;
  }
  public function runReport($reportID) {
    $newID = $this->client->runReport($reportID);
    $counter = 0;
    while($this->client->checkReportRun($newID) != 'complete'){
      if($counter > 2) {
        throw new Exception('Report Time Out');
      }
      sleep(5);
      $counter++;
    }
    $this->getDataObject($newID);
    return $newID;
  }

  public function functest() {
    $v0 = $this->getDataObject('id')->result_count;
    return $this->getDataObject('id')->data;
  }

  public function getLatestID($reportID) {
    $runlist = $this->client->getReportRunList($reportID);
    return $runlist[0][0];
  }

  public function getLatestReportData($reportID) {
    return $this->getReportData($this->getLatestID($reportID));
  }

  public function getTitles($reportID) {
    return $this->getDataObject($reportID)->columns;
  }

  public function getReportRunTime($reportID) {
    $runlist = $this->client->getReportRunList($reportID);
    return strtotime($runlist[0][2]);
  }

  public function getRawReport($reportID) {
    return $this->client->getReportDataObject($reportID);
  }

  protected function getDataObject($reportID) {
    if(!isset($this->reportDataObject) || $this->reportDataObject->report_run_id != $reportID) {
      $this->reportDataObject = $this->client->getReportDataObject($reportID);
    }
    return $this->reportDataObject;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: As an after thought I tried adding the keep_alive option to the SoapClient but it didn't help.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: What is the error code? Can you run wireshark or charles to see what network traffic is being sent?

You might want to keep an eye out for CSRF tokens or rate limiting if the server is giving you an error when repeating the same request.

Comment: @DavidLai: It didn't return an error code, just the 'Bad Request'.  I'm still leaning towards something up with my server settings because the issue only started after an update, and same code works as expected on PHP 5.4.  I've been getting around the issue by creating new SoapClient objects and using one call each.  I don't suspect rate limiting because it usually at most 2-3 requests.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It was working perfectly on PHP 5.5, but not on 5.6. I have the same php.ini configuration file, and I added a 'stream_context' option to avoid the PHP 5.6 new standard with SSL certification checking. So far I found no solution to the problem, other than reinitializing the object each time.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was fixed in PHP 5.6.1. While I couldn't find any reference to this issue in the change logs, after installing 5.6.1 I can reuse a SoapClient object and do subsequent __doRequest() calls.

[PHP Download Link](https://www.php.net/downloads.php)

Comment: Great! I'll test it out.  I ended up going back my previous 5.4 installation, but I'll test out the latest update. Thanks.

Comment: @latca, If this will not help, give me HTTP request and response XML's:

    `try {
        ...
    } catch (\Behat\Behat\Exception\Exception) {
        var_dump(array(
            'request' => $client->__getLastRequest(),
            'requestHeaders' => $client->__getLastRequestHeaders(),
            'response' => $client->__getLastResponse(),
            'responseHeaders' => $client->__getLastResponseHeaders()
        ));
    }`

Comment: The bug this is about is probably: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67955 - it's listed in the changelog http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.1 under SOAP

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, but relating that to the behaviour described here is quite difficult. Thanks for the comment.